# Numerical integration with a variable

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have to do the next integral:
$\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{660 r Sin[kr]}{k(72000+e^{1.85r})}dr}$

This integral is actually a 3D Fourier transform so I need to obtain the result as a function of k, perhaps an approximate function. A fit function?
I tried to do it by using `NIntegrate`

```
ff[k_,r_] = Integrate[(1/(2Pi^2))(660*r*Sin[k r]*r) / (k(72000+Exp[1.85r])),{r,0,Infinity}]
```

but there are several mistakes. Can anybody tell me what command should I use to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already have my answer for the analogous case here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153888/integrating-a-difficult-function-numerically/153893#153893 This your new integral is the same story. You should do it analogously. I propose to close this question since it already has the answer.

Comment: Okay , thank yoy very much for your help, again :D. I will close this question as soon as I know how to do that :D. Have a nice weekend Alexei

Comment: Hi, Jhoan, my proposal is addressed to the community. According to the rules of this site, it tries to keep only original questions in its archive, otherwise, the archive will blow up. It has nothing to do with personalities or, say, the question asked. I am for asking any questions people have. But it's just a rule. The question is being closed when several members with a certain reputation level propose to close it. My proposal only is not enough.